# How can I use atexit() function to cleanup function call?

Tags: c, exit, atexit

I am using atexit() function inside my code to cleanup function call, but it's not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void ftn(void)
{
    printf(" Function called --> exit\n");
    return;
}
int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    atexit(ftn);
    for(;x<0xffffff;x++);
    _exit(0);
}
```

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: You should mostly call `_exit` ever when in a child process after a `fork` and you must not call the original cleanup code because the clean up belongs to the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior of atexit() function is due to the use of function _exit(). This function does not call the clean-up functions like atexit() etc. If atexit() is required to be called then exit() or ‘return’ should be used instead of _exit().

As:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void ftn(void)
{
    printf(" Function called --> exit\n");
    return;
}
int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    atexit(ftn);
    for(;x<0xffffff;x++);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`_exit` close the program without calling at exit methods [Further reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/_Exit).

Thus, use `exit(0);` instead of `_exit(0);`

```
#include<stdio.h>
void ftn(void)
{
    printf(" Function called --> exit\n");
    return;
}
int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    atexit(ftn);
    for(;x<0xffffff;x++);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting the man page for `_exit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/_exit)

> The `_Exit()` and `_exit()` functions **shall not call functions registered with `atexit()`** nor any registered signal handlers. Whether open streams are flushed or closed, or temporary files are removed is implementation-defined. Finally, the calling process is terminated with the consequences described below.

So what you're seeing is expected behavior.

That said, you should include `unistd.h` (for `_exit()`)and `stdlib.h` (for `atexit()`) headers for including the prototype.

If you want the functions registered by `atexit()` to be invoked, you should call `exit()` instead.

> The `exit()` function shall first call all functions registered by `atexit()`, in the reverse order of their registration, [....]